# How to test controller helper statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have `checkouts_controller.rb` with action:

```
def create
    if create_customer(params[:stripeToken], @plan.my_plan_id, params[:code], params[:new_price])
      redirect_to user_path(id: current_user.to_param, customer_share: true)
    else
      redirect_to new_checkout_path(plan_id: @plan)
    end
end
```

In `users_helper.rb`:

```
def create_customer
if customer != nil
...
else
flash[:error] = 'Something went wrong, please try again.'
end
```

So I need to check else and test it in rspec for `flash[:error]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have passed `flash` as an argument to my `create_customer` to [make the code testable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36723902/52317). That's also aligned with OOP principles.

But, if you really have to test the code as it is, then:

```
module UsersHelper
  def flash
    @flash ||= {}
  end
end

describe UsersHelper do
  subject { Object.new.extend(described_class) }

  context 'Customer does not exist' do
    it 'sets flash mesage' do
      # your test code
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Fires Stripe::InvalidRequestError

Comment: Apparently you are using `stripe-ruby` gem. You will have fulfil all stripe related requirements.